# intercepting XHR requests, javascript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to override the methods in order to intercept the xhr requests but seems like everything I do it only prinds '1' for this.readyState.
Does anyone have any idea why?

```
    addInterceptorsToXHRRequests() {
    const originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        const originalStateChangeHandler = this.onreadystatechange;
        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log(' ---> ',this.readyState);
            if (originalStateChangeHandler instanceof Function) {
                originalStateChangeHandler.apply(this, arguments);
                console.log('Ready state: ' + this.readyState);
            }
        };
        return originalOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

I am calling this function from index.js, at the end of componentDidMount life cycle method. (pretty big project)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you bind a function on **XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open** .

**open** returns only state 1.
So, you need to attach the onreadystatechange function to the full xhr.

**Example**

```
// you probably want the original XMLHttpRequest here...
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   console.log(xhr.readyState);
};
```